# cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>' error when trying to use `TryParse`

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# and I'm having troubles. I'm getting `cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>'` error when I try to use `!double.TryParse`

```cs
static double userDouble, correctDouble;
static void someMethod() {
         Console.Write(someStringOfDoubles);
         while(!double.TryParse(userDouble, out _)) {
            try {
               userDouble= Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch {
               Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(userDouble)} is an invalid input\n\n");
            }
         }
         // checks if the userDouble is correct or not.
         if (Math.Round(correctDouble, 2) == userDouble) {
            Console.WriteLine("You are Correct!\n");
         }
         else {
            Console.WriteLine("You are Incorrect.");
         }
      }
```

**What should it do**: Check if `userDouble` is a valid double and not letter(s)/word(s).

I also tried:

```cs
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userDouble)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(userDouble)} is an invalid input\n\n");
}
```

but this gives me `No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How you have declared variable `userDouble`? Your second try should work if you have `userDouble` declared as `double`.

Comment: `userDouble` is declared as `static double`. My second try also gives me an error `No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 argument`. I've been stuck here for a while.
 Updated my post for future readers. Thank you!

Comment: Your code: `while(!double.TryParse(userDouble, out _)) {`. Your comment: _"userDouble is declared as static double"_ - then what do you expect `TryParse` to do with `userDouble`?

Comment: Your second attempt is correct and doesn't give you that error message.

Comment: if `userDouble` is `double` then it should show error like `cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>` because there are no overload method of `double.TryParse` which accepts `doubls` as first parameter. Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Comment: I would like `TryParse` to check if the user inputs a character or a double, and if the user tried to input a character/string, it should display some string saying invalid input and ask for another input again. Should I remove it as static?

Comment: @Kyle `double userDouble` is _already a double_ so there is no need to try and parse it. Parsing is intended for trying to interpret a `string` as a `double` (or whatever other type you're parsing to). As I said before, your second attempt is correct and doesn't produce that error. The error message line isn't correct though, so Karan's answer will solve that problem for you.

Comment: @Karan I understand now! `double.TryParse` can only parse other types except its own double. Of course, it won't check if it is already a double! So since it is already double I wouldn't need the `TryParse` and just use try-catch if the user attempts to enter a non-double input. Am I right?

Comment: @Kyle There is no such thing as a double containing a non-double input. There is no way to create a double with "non-double" input. User input via `Console.ReadLine()` is _only_ as a `string` (text). To get a `double` (which is a number type) you have to parse it.

Comment: @John Thank you for clarifying! I understand it clearly now. Appreciated much your response. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get console value in string variable first then check it with `double.TryParse(...)`. Try like below.

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
while(!double.TryParse(s, out userDouble)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{s} is an invalid input\n\n");
    s = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

Below attempt of yours must work without any error. But only problem you will face is it will write `0 is an invalid input` for evert input because `double.TryParse` will set `userDouble = 0` when value from `Console.ReadLine()` are not `double`.

```
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userDouble)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(userDouble)} is an invalid input\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for more clarification! I just have a question. Why doing `string s = Console.ReadLine();` and `while(!double.TryParse(s, out userDouble)) {...}` makes an infinite loop displaying the `Conole.WriteLine("Invalid Input")`. But `while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userDouble)) {...}` doesn't make an infinite loop but it doesn't display the `Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input")` when user entered a character/string? It will just display the second time around the user entered a character/string.

Comment: I got it now, I forgot to add the `s = Console.ReadLine();` inside the while loop. Thank you again!

Comment: Add `s = Console.ReadLine();` at the end of `while` loop. So for next iteration latest value will be check inside `condition`.